# browser capability detection within angular app: use service, directive, controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture, modernizr

If this question is too general or subjective, let me know and I'll figure out how better to phrase it.

I'm looking to implement some browser compatibility checking and notification in an angular app. I'm using `Modernizr` which is great. The client does not actually want to do much in the way of polyfills, but rather is looking to give an "upgrade to a real browser" notification to users with browsers below the minimum spec.

My question is what the appropriate angular component for implementing this is. I'd like to do this check as soon as possible in the page load/compile process, but I'm not yet expert enough with angular to have much confidence in my choices. Moreover, I want to learn the appropriate organization of angular apps so future programmers don't have to deal with strange mutants that I've cobbled together...

Comment: its not exactly what you are asking for, but there are a number of services like browsehappy (http://browsehappy.com/) that do this notification for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the check on the .run() of your main application module.

I suggest that you read [this style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) for best practices - it has chapters on how to organize your app. If you follow the conventions there you will surely end up with a structure others can contribute to.
Moreover, you can use a [boilerplate like this](https://github.com/ngbp) to get some structure 'for free'. That's a good way to learn and you will probably develop faster once you get the hang of it.

Lastly, to better understand the 'component flow' in Angular you could create all components on a module and then 'console.log()' to see their execution order. Better yet, [here's a snippet](http://jsbin.com/vilere/14/) that does that if you don't feel like doing it yourself. (Check the console)